# Android facebook authorization. Can not log in when official Facebook app is installed

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

I need to login to Facebook and get fields like e-mail, username, photo etc. I use the Facebook SDK. When official Facebook app is not installed, after pushing log in button, opening web-view window, which request mail and password, and then, I can get token and data. But when installed official Facebook app on the device, my application doen not work, I push log in button, but I not see a dialog (Facebook activity is not starting). I use login without standart Facebook LogInButton. How I can to resolve it ?

```
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this);
            callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
            LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult) {
                    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject jsonObject, GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                            Bundle bFacebookData = getFacebookData(jsonObject);
                            new FacebookAuthorization(AuthenticationActivity.this, loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken(),
                                    bFacebookData.getString("name"),
                                    bFacebookData.getString("profile_pic"),
                                    bFacebookData.getString("email")).execute();
                        }
                    });
                    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                    parameters.putString("fields", "id, first_name, last_name, email,gender, birthday, location");
                    request.setParameters(parameters);
                    request.executeAsync();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException e) {

                }
            });
    }

    public void facebookAuth(View v){
            if (new InternetConnection(getApplicationContext()).isNetworkConnection()) {
                LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends"));
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.no_internet_connection), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if(callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
            return;
        }
    }

    private Bundle getFacebookData(JSONObject object) {
            try {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                String id = object.getString("id");

                try {
                    URL profile_pic = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture?width=200&height=150");
                    bundle.putString("profile_pic", profile_pic.toString());
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
                if (object.has("first_name") && object.has("last_name")){
                    bundle.putString("name", object.getString("first_name") + " " + object.getString("last_name"));
                }
                if (object.has("email")){
                    bundle.putString("email", object.getString("email"));
                }
                return bundle;
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Is the Facebook app set to auto-login? You can check this with AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(); If it's not null then the user is already logged in.

Comment: @ZengoTim how to disable auto-login ?

Comment: @ZengoTim AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() = null it's because in onDestroy() I do LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();

Comment: oh well there went my whole theory :-)

Comment: @ZengoTim When I only install Facebook app, after login pushing, it's launch Facebook activity, I enter mail and password, but after that nothing to doing